# I could not download .publishsettings in Macintosh

Tags: azure

Now, I use Windows Azure of free experience version.
I want to download  .publishsettings to use command line tool, but I can't download it.
I try it on with any browsers, but I couldn't....

Comment: ...what sort of problem did you run into?

Comment: I assume you're browsing to http://windows.azure.com/download/publishprofile.aspx - what happens when you do that?

Answer (score 0):

'azure account download' from the command line tool should allow you to download a publishsettings file.  If not, what is the issue that you see?